# Add recurring event for 2 years

Tags: android, cordova, calendar, recurring-events

I want to add a recurring event in the calendar programatically., i.e directly without using intent.
I user the following ::

```
ContentResolver cr = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(Events.DTSTART, calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.DTEND, calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
      values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
      values.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY"); //For recurring event
      values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

      Uri uri = cr.insert(eventsUri, values);
```

The event is only added for 2 weeks . I want it to be added for atleast 2 years or more.., can be  forever also.
I have used the Combinations UNTIL also,, but nothing works. Wat should I update the code with.. Any help.. Thanks

Comment: Phonegap Developer chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,
add

```
values.put(Events.DURATION, "P0600S");
```

Remove

```
values.put(Events.DTEND, calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: For adding a recurring event the DTEND should be removed and duration part must be added.. Finally this worked,.. Thank u :)

Comment: have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871921/add-weekly-event-to-calendar

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be like

```
values.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=2");
```

This will make the event for every 2 years.

You can tweak the INTERVAL as you need it.

More more options on this refer http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html